# What's happening to my uft-8 strings in Postgresql?

Tags: perl, postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, dbix-class

In my process I parse google maps kml and feed it with perl into a database, via [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class).

If I pull the data out with psql, everything looks fine, but if I pull it via `DBIx::Class` all utf-8 chars look mangled.

The exact same process done in sqlite3 works like a charm.

I have `pg_enable_utf8` enabled on the client side.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Exactly how are you pulling it via `DBIx::Class`, any code to demonstrate it?

Comment: Please **show your code**. Also, what locale is the Perl interpreter running in? Did you read [the manual for DBI::Pg's `pg_enable_utf8`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm#pg_enable_utf8_%28integer%29)?

Comment: It turns out that it is solved by using `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");` when printing to STDOUT and setting `encoding => "UTF-8"` on Catalyst. I wonder why that wasn't necessary with sqlite though.

Comment: I guess you didn't setup SQLite correctly so the UTF-8 data coming from SQLite wasn't decoded so it was still encoded as UTF-8 when you printed it to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/UTF8Columns.pm#Warning_-_Module_does_not_function_properly_on_create/insert

If you are using `INSERT`, then perhaps the above warning pertains to your process.

Also, maybe having your script execute `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'value';` on the server will help, where value = UTF8.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/multibyte.html for further info.